# Orthonormality of vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I want to show that the following Riemannian manifold with given metric $g$ the following vector fields are orthonormal at every point $p$ of the manifold.

Let $\mathcal{H}^3=\lbrace (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid z>0\rbrace$ be equipped with the Riemannian metric:
\begin{equation*}
g=\frac{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}{z^2}
\end{equation*}
And the vector fields $A,B,C$ defined as:
\begin{equation*}
A=z\partial_x, \quad B=z\partial_y, \quad C=z\partial_z
\end{equation*}

Trying to plug the vector spaces into the definition of $g$ gives:

\begin{equation}
g(A,B)=\frac{dx(z\partial_x)dx(z\partial_y)+dy(z\partial_x)dy(z\partial_y)+dz(z\partial_x)dz(z\partial_y)}{z^2}
\end{equation}

But since all the terms in the numerator vanish this expression is zero.

Comment: at the beginning the metric is a (bilinear) function taking two vectors of the tangent space at some point $p$ and output their inner product (hence it is one bilinear operator $T_pM \times T_pM \to \mathbb{R}$ for each point $p$)

Comment: In fact, you have just proved that $g(A,B)=0$, which means that $A \perp B$, which is just fine. Isn't this a part of what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that part I have solved, the vectors being unit vectors are a little more  tricky, I find.

Comment: Unity is also easy, just use that $dx(z\partial_x)=zdx(\partial_x)$.

Comment: Using the norm induced by $g$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way in which $g$ is written is maybe the cause for the confusion. Try writing it like this:

$$g(X,Y)=\frac{dx(X)dx(Y)+dy(X)dy(Y)+dz(X)dz(Y)}{z^2} $$

Now it should be clear that $dx(\partial_x)=dz(\partial_z)=dy(\partial_y)=1$ and $dy(\partial_x)=0$ which also holds for all other combinations (i.e. $dy(\partial_z)$ etc.).

Can you figure it out from here on or do you need more help?

Comment: That helped quite a bit, since that makes more sense. The notations are really not intuitive in geometry. When writing $dx(\partial_x)$ does that mean taking the derivative of $\partial_x$ w.r.t $x$? Am I right in assuming that proving orthogonality requires only that $g_p(X,Y)=0$ for $X,Y$ being $A$,$B$ or $C$ for any point $p \in \mathcal(H)^3$?

Comment: $\partial_x$ is just a vector field. And since your manifold is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is very easy to compute. In general you have a chart $\varphi:M \to U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and you take $\partial_{x_i}:=d\varphi^{-1}(e_i)$ where $e_i$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now in this case your chart is the identity and so $\partial_z=(0,0,1)$. The $dx,dy,dz$ are just the dual basis.

Comment: You're right about orthogonality you need that $g_p(X(p),Y(p))=0$ for all $p$.

Comment: Okay, I am not particularly comfortable with dual bases, so what does the notation $dx(\partial_x)$ mean in a more elementary sense?

Comment: $dx$ is a one-form with the precise property $dx(\partial_x)=1$ and $dx(\partial_y)=dx(\partial_z)=0$. So if you have a vectorfield $X$ that is locally given by $X=f_x\partial_x+f_y\partial_y+f_z\partial_z$ where $f_x,f_y,f_z$ are functions from $M \to \mathbb{R}$ then $dx(X)=f_x$.

Comment: This is really all there is, you can plug in vectorfields and get back functions. And they are linear with respect to functions form $M \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $dx(fX+gY)=fdx(X)+gdx(Y)$.

Comment: Well, I seem to get that the expressions you wrote in your answer are all zero, even without evaluating at a point $p$, is this true?

Comment: Yes, thats true. Also I would highly recommend going over the basics again: tangent spaces, canonical basis and dual tangent space.